# How do I prevent Terraform from destroying the virtual machine after changing keyvault.?

Tags: azure, terraform

The secret password of the existing KeyVault has expired and has been changed. Then my VM is destroyed and recreated. Is there any way to stop this? All codes are written in terraform.

keyvault.tf

```
## Keyvault Creation
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "kv" {
  name                = var.kv_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.system_rg
  tenant_id           = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  sku_name            = var.sku_name

  soft_delete_retention_days      = var.soft_delete_retention_days
  enabled_for_deployment          = var.enabled_for_deployment
  enabled_for_disk_encryption     = var.enabled_for_disk_encryption
  enabled_for_template_deployment = var.enabled_for_template_deployment
  purge_protection_enabled        = var.purge_protection_enabled
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "access_policy" {
  for_each     = var.access_policy
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.kv.id

  tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id = each.value.object_id

  secret_permissions      = each.value.secret_permissions
  key_permissions         = each.value.key_permissions
  certificate_permissions = each.value.certificate_permissions
  storage_permissions     = each.value.storage_permissions
}

## Create Key Vault Secret
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "password" {
  name         = var.kv_secret_name
  value        = var.password_value
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
  depends_on   = [azurerm_key_vault.kv]
}
```

vm.tf

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "system_rg" {
  name     = "${var.system_rg}"
  location = "${var.location}"
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "system_rg_name" {
  name = azurerm_resource_group.system_rg.name
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "network-subnet" {
  name                 = "${var.network_subnet}"
  virtual_network_name = "${var.network_vnet}"
  resource_group_name  = "${var.network_rg}"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault" "kv" {
  name = var.kv_name
  resource_group_name = var.kv_rg
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "password" {
  name = var.kv_secret_name
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
  for_each                      = "${var.vm_template}"
  name                          = "${each.value.vm_name}-${each.value.nic}"
  location                      = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name           = data.azurerm_resource_group.system_rg_name.name
  enable_accelerated_networking = true
  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = data.azurerm_subnet.network-subnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "${var.private-ip-type}"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  for_each = var.vm_template
  name                = each.value.vm_name
  location            = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.system_rg_name.name
  size = each.value.vm_type
  source_image_id     = each.value.source_image_id
  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.nic[each.key].id,
  ]

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
  
  os_disk {
    name                 = "${each.value.vm_name}-${each.value.os_disk}"
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = each.value.osdisk_type
    disk_size_gb         = each.value.osdisk_size
  }

  plan {
    name      = each.value.os_sku
    publisher = each.value.os_publisher
    product   = each.value.os_offer
  }

  computer_name  = each.value.hostname
  admin_username = "${var.adminid}"
  admin_password = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.password.value  
  disable_password_authentication = false

}
```

If I apply Terraform in this state, I'm going to destroy my Virtual Machine and recreate it as shown below.

```
 # azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm["vm1"] must be replaced
-/+ resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "vm" {
      ~ admin_password             = (sensitive value) # forces replacement
      - encryption_at_host_enabled = false -> null
      ~ id                         = "/subscriptions/.../vm-testwindows" -> (known after apply)
        name                       = "vm-testwindows"
      + public_ip_address          = (known after apply)
      ~ public_ip_addresses        = [] -> (known after apply)
      - secure_boot_enabled        = false -> null
      - tags                       = {} -> null
      ~ virtual_machine_id         = ""xxxxx-xxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx" " -> (known after apply)
      - vtpm_enabled               = false -> null
        # (18 unchanged attributes hidden)

      ~ identity {
          - identity_ids = [] -> null
          ~ principal_id = "xxxxx-xxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx" -> (known after apply)
          ~ tenant_id    = "xxxxx-xxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx" -> (known after apply)
            # (1 unchanged attribute hidden)
        }

        # (3 unchanged blocks hidden)
    }

Plan: 3 to add, 0 to change, 3 to destroy.
```

The first time I applied Keyvault secret password, I only got a "change" state, but I don't know why I'm trying to recreate Virtual Machine like this when I apply it after the secret password expires.

I ask for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you would use [lifecycle Meta-Argument](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle) of `ignore_changes`:

```
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "vm" {

 #...

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      admin_password,
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, if you do that, you will not recreate the Virtual Machine, but you will not be able to access the password you changed. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: Can I change the admin password in keyvault and apply it to a virtual machine in real time?

Comment: @gotothesky Sadly you can't. You either enable replacement of the vm, or you manually update passwords.